# MATLAB: Draw an arrow of set magnitude from a point, in the direction to another point

Tags: matlab

I want to draw an arrow from one point **towards** another point with a given magnitude.

For example, two points have coordinates (x,y) = (0,0) and (1,1), respectively.

Draw an arrow beginning at (0,0) with magnitude (length) `mag_pt1_pt2` towards (1,1).

I want to repeat this for some 400 points then draw a vector field.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a matlab library that someone has written to do that:

http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278-arrow-m

given the OP's comments about the answer he can do this:

```
function [] = arrowLandD(x1, y1, length, x2, y2)
    direction = arctan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
    p2 = [x1+length*cos(direction) y1+length*sin(direction)];
    arrow([x1 y1], p2);
end
```

to make arrow into a plot of length and direction from starting point rather than p1->p2.

You can also use the inbuilt vector field library quiver:

http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html

To produce stuff like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: The documentation suggests that a start and stop point of the arrow are required, with the `length` property being the length of the arrowhead (not the arrow). [link](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278-arrow-m/content/arrow.m)

Comment: @janon128 The arrow will go from point 1 to point 2. You can define the size of the arrow head how you want. Also you can use quiver if you are not happy with arrow.m

Comment: I think you're mis-understanding my question. The arrow should not end at point 2. I define it's length; it only points towards point2, not end at point 2.

Comment: @janon128 Then you can make a point in between point 1 and 2 based on the magnitude and use that to define the end of the arrow. Or use quiver, which is designed for what you are doing. Or you could edit arrow to take a length and direction and plot based on that. This is a suggestion for the direction you can take, not an exact answer.

Comment: @janon128 There you go i fixed it based on your comment. That was easy wasn't it?